# Collision of a photon with a quasi-free particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, photons, atomic-physics, protons

What is a quasi-free proton?

How does the wavelength of a photon change when it collides with a quasi-free particle, e.g. a quasi-free proton?

Comment: where did you get this terminology? Electrons might be called "quasi-free" in a metal when modeled with the band theory of solids, because they are bound by the whole lattice, not atoms. Protons are always either free or bound, afaik.

Comment: @annav yeah, I know about the quasi-free electrons. 
This question was actually a homework question that I had a week ago in experimental physics. I've searched about quasi-free protons or neutrons, but I didn't find any useful information. That is why I asked here.

Comment: In order to calculate the wavelength change, I was thinking of using the Compton scattering formula, but instead of using the electron's mass, the proton's mass should be used. But the term "quasi-free' particle is pretty unclear for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Live and [keep learning:](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.38.121)

> Quasi-free processes in nuclei are reviewed both from a theoretical and an experimental point of view. The discussion is limited to nuclei with mass number≥4 and to incident energies larger than 100 MeV for quasi-free proton-proton and 300 MeV for electron-proton scattering. The reactions are discussed qualitatively, and their relevance for the investigation of nuclear shells, in particular of the strongly bound ones, is shown. The cross section for quasi-free scattering is then derived in the distorted wave impulse approximation, and some special cases are considered. Through a few examples the main features of the experimental results are presented and compared with calculated ones.

And [here is a measurement:](https://arxiv.org/abs/nucl-ex/0003002).

(Compton scattering on a proton is [discussed here.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/325678/compton-like-scattering-for-protons))

Imo , the quasi part refers to the energy binding the proton in the nucleus  which has to be taken into account.

With electrons in the conduction band it is the photoelectric effect, with the work function.

Here is [an ancient paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/96561).